# Add React native video/voice call

Tags: react-native, voximplant

Will [onsip](https://www.onsip.com/) support React Native? How to a add voice/video call feature in React Native App?

I am trying [with react-native-voximplant](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/react-native-sdk/using-react-native-sdk) which requires

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.+'
```

and

```
distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

But it throws this error:

> could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.+

for any versions grater than 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest Android Studio it will be enough to make a project modifications highlighted in the [SDK tutorial](https://voximplant.com/docs/references/react-native-sdk/using-react-native-sdk).

Comment: Voximplant is using WebRTC concept. Will WebRTC support all browsers? Will it work properly for IOS and Android?

Comment: Right now all major browsers are supported, including mobile Android and iOS. Voximplant also has native mobile SDK's for Android and iOS, alongside with React Native and Unity (sic!)